# How to obtain a CORBA IOR

Tags: corba

I'm working from a CORBA [network management spec](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v8r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc/probes/ericsson_ossrc/ericsson_ossrc/wip/reference/ecossrc_devices.html) and I want to obtain the IOR file which contains the information I need to connect to the CORBA service. There is some information about how to obtain the "ExternalNameService.ior" file from the link I posted, but I am not sure what to do. Basically I have an idea of what I want to do which is:

1. Obtain the IOR.
2. Decode it so that I get the IP and Port of the CORBA service.
3. Compile the IDLs and use them to connect to the remote resources.

The part I'm stuck on is obtaining the IOR. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to provide my own implementation of a probe...not use IBM's. The article simple shows the name of the naming service, which I cannot connect to for some reason...that's my biggest problem. The following code works if I try to connect to a local name service, but fails for the ericsson one. I am providing the right `ORBInitialPort` and `ORBInitialHost` as command line arguments.

```
  ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);
  String corbalocURL = "ExternalNameService";
  // get the root naming context
  org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references(corbalocURL);
  // Use NamingContextExt instead of NamingContext. This is
  // part of the Interoperable naming Service.
  System.out.println(objRef);
  NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);
  System.out.println(ncRef);
```

These are Errors I'm getting:

```
ERROR : org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.getSystemException(MessageBase.java:914)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.ReplyMessage_1_0.getSystemException(ReplyMessage_1_0.java:111)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.getSystemExceptionReply(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:590)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:459)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.invoke(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.list(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:151)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.list(CompositeResolverImpl.java:55)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.list(CompositeResolverImpl.java:55)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.list(CompositeResolverImpl.java:55)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.list_initial_services(ORBImpl.java:1143)
    at HelloClient.main(HelloClient.java:22)
```

Comment: Did you manage to get the IOR ? I mean the com.sun.corba.se.spi.ior.IOR object. Another E/// guy (ealnmar). Also Corba through RSG is not possible AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

You should never do #2. CORBA was designed to hide network details from you. Plus, IORs are not always bound to TCP/IP and therefore might not even contain a host or port (although they almost always do).

I'd recommend learning a little more about CORBA before going much further. [This](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/) is a good intro site.

IORs are the "handles" to your server objects, and are meant to be opaque blobs of data that you just use to call the remote resources to which they refer. They're like phone numbers for people - a means to enable communication.

If you don't have an IOR string in a file somewhere, you might be able to find the IOR in a Naming Service running somewhere (it's like a "White Pages" directory for IORs).

Comment: It also looks like you don't need to do this yourself for the 'probe' implementation that you linked to - the documentation states that you just need to set a property that points to the NameService or to a URL that serves the IOR

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek please read my update, let me know if you need more info..thanks for the help

Comment: Well, honestly, I'm almost sorry I jumped in here - it's been a number of years since I did anything with CORBA, and I'm clearly out of my depth here. However, you are clearly having issues with the naming server - may I suggest plugging "CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST" into your favorite search engine?

Comment: thanks for the feedback..I'll write back when I come up with a solution...in case anyone is interested